# Dual DVI external monitors from laptop using HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I know there may be a few questions similar to this, but my question is regarding specific hardware configuration.

I have an Asus U52f laptop with an HDMI out that I currently use to drive my 24" DVI external monitor.  My question is I found an HDMI -> dual DVI splitter [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FMPR0Q) and was wanting to know is has anyone tried this type of configuration or would the Matrox DualHead2Go be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a clone (you call it mirror when mirror would be right and left sides swapped) mode only then 5€ splitter will do the thing. Matrox has more functionality.

Comment: But will the splitter give me an expanded desktop or just show the same desktop twice (mirror)?

Comment: There are DVI-HDMI cables on the market just use that.  I bought it on Newegg for $15 worked perfectly with my HDMI monitors and my DVI graphic card.  What the laptop displays on that monitor will be based on what you set it to.

Comment: Standard splitters will only mirror - they do not change the available bandwidth to the display(s).  The BEST solution, if you don't need ridiculous levels of performance, is to buy a DisplayLink-based USB video adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on what you are looking to accomplish. A splitter just replicates the same image on all outputs. It does not support extended desktop applications.